# Chat Application using Spring boot RSocket

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rsocket, rsocket-java

I am using Spring boot 2.5.0 with the react front end.
Trying to use RSocket for building a chat application.

Came across the following links. But, still not clear on sending message to a particular user.

> RSocket doc -->
> https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.8-SNAPSHOT/reference/pdf/rsocket.pdf
>
> Medium -->
> https://medium.com/swlh/building-a-chat-application-with-angular-and-spring-rsocket-3cd8013f2f55
>
> RSocket Demo ->
> https://github.com/benwilcock/spring-rsocket-demo/blob/master/rsocket-server/src/main/java/io/pivotal/rsocketserver/RSocketController.java

My application is a multi tenant application. Each tenant might have 3 to 10 users.

Use cases, For any given tenant,

1. Store messages in the server
2. Should be able to list the users online
3. Send message to all users belongs to a particular tenant
4. Send message to a particular user from a tenant

I have the following config.

In build.gradle,

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-rsocket'
```

application.properties,

```
spring.rsocket.server.mapping-path= /rsocket
spring.rsocket.server.transport= websocket
```

RSocketController.java

```
@MessageMapping("fire-and-forget")
    public Mono<Void> fireAndForget(final Message request, @AuthenticationPrincipal UserDetails user) {
        return Mono.empty();
    }
```

Here, I am able to get the user message and need to route this to a particular user/users. How can I find all users online and route message to a particular user/users?

Comment: These are prety barebones examples you have pointed at, most of what you are asking for would be additional functionality you would need to build on top.  None of the examples are intende to be at the level of a polished functioning chat app, just tech demo.